# CSS Modules "Unexpected token ."

Tags: css, reactjs

Пытаюсь использовать CSS Modules в приложении React. Выпадает такая ошибка в стилях: "Unexpected token ." при пересборке webpack.

Webpack:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

export default {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
            {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Component:

```
import React , { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import style from './LoginComponent.css';

class LoginComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={style.login}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default LoginComponent;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так сделал?

Comment: Добавьте скрин ошибки, пока ясно, что при сборке не получается прочитать точку, а где именно не понятно.

Comment: Надо было лоэдеры sass-loader, style-loader подгрузить и в вепаке их использовать.